# "TypeError: product_show() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Option'"

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have build up a menu with numbers, and my selection variable is `Option` with type int. `5-Hoodie` will show all the stuff with category is `Hoodie` in my SQL database. I have created a module and I am using the class named `LunaPy`

```
Option = int(input("Option: "))
LunaPy.product_show(Option)
```

I am using SQL library in Python

```
    def product_show(self,Option):
        product_dict ={1:"Belt",2:"Blazer",3:"Coat",4:"Dress",5:"Hoodie",6:"Jacket",7:"Jeans",8:"Pants",9:"Shoes",10:"Shorts",11:"Sunglasses",12:"Sweater",13:"SweatShirt",14:"TShirt",15:"Underwear"}

        query = "SELECT * FROM LunaPyDataBase WHERE Category = ?"
        self.cursor.execute(query,(product_dict[Option],))
```

I expected the `Option` variable would return the value to the function so the function can use that to select the category in dictionary. And prints the items in that chosen category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method to this:

```py
@staticmethod
def product_show(Option):
    product_dict ={1:"Belt",2:"Blazer",3:"Coat",4:"Dress",5:"Hoodie",6:"Jacket",7:"Jeans",8:"Pants",9:"Shoes",10:"Shorts",11:"Sunglasses",12:"Sweater",13:"SweatShirt",14:"TShirt",15:"Underwear"}

    query = "SELECT * FROM LunaPyDataBase WHERE Category = ?"
    self.cursor.execute(query,(product_dict[Option],))
```

Or do this:

```py
option = int(input("Option: "))
lunaPy = LunaPy()

lunaPy.product_show(option)
```

The `self` in your function definition points to the object instance of your `LunaPy` class. If your method does not require an instance of `LunaPy`, you can mark it as static... and then you can use it like this `Class.method()`, but won't be able to use any instance variables or methods of the class.

The other option is to just create the instance and call the method using that.

**EDIT:**

Didn't notice the `self` inside the function. The first option won't work, because object instance is required. The second option with `lunaPy = LunaPy()` should work though.